# Tomcat commits response too early on concurrent requests

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I have a problem that Tomcat 8.5 is committing responses far too early. If there are several concurrent requests it can happen that a response is committed directly after a filter that is adding just four small headers (Spring Security in my case), so I cannot set the status anymore in the servlet. Is there any shared buffer or something like that I could increase to avoid such behavior?

If there is no such configuration I have to wrap the response in a way to cache the headers until there is a body written or or the response is ready, are there any best practices or ready-to-use implementations?

Comment: Are you sure you (or spring) is not calling `flush()` on the servlet output stream or on the response print writer ? You can set an access breakpoint on the `volatile boolean commited = false` field in `org.apache.coyote.Response` in order to check who's commiting the reponse

Comment: Yes, I've already used Springs [OnCommittedResponseWrapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java) to log all access to the response which would flush the response, and have writte also a very ugly java-proxy with ByteBuddy to track ALL method calls on the response, and there is only the addHeader() calls of spring security and next the try to set the status which is not working because the response is committed.

Comment: I cannot set any breakpoints as the problem does not occur if started with the debugger :( I already thought about changing the tomcat source code and add logging when the response is committed with `new Exception()` to get a stack trace...

Comment: How big are your header values? Tomcat's buffer can be auto-flushed if the size of the in-memory response exceeds the size of that buffer. You may just need to increase that buffer size.